# annotated post and get on same method

Tags: java, spring, rest

may i know is it possible to annotate one method with 2 post and get ?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/testonly", 
                method = RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST)
public String getSomething(){

}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The `method` field is an array, so I'd expect this to work:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/testonly",
                method = { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST })
```

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't supposed to pass method type as both GET and POST. It will throw unexpected exception if we pass both GET and POST.

Regards,
Raja Sekhar.